# Discord.py get_user(id)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I try to add a leaderboard feature to my economy bot. But I got this Error:
`Command raised an exception: AttributeError: module 'discord.ext.commands' has no attribute 'get_user'`
I think I need to add another library or something like that.
Here is my complete code:

```
@commands.command()
    async def leaderboard(self, ctx, x=1):
        users = await self.get_bank_data()
        leader_board = {}
        total = []
        for user in users:
            name = int(user)
            total_amount = users[user]["wallet"] + users[user]["bank"]
            leader_board[total_amount] = name
            total.append(total_amount)

        total = sorted(total, reverse=True)

        em = discord.Embed(title=f"Top {x} Richest People",
                           description="This is decided on the basis of raw money in the bank and wallet",
                           color=random.randint(0, 0xffffff))
        index = 1
        for amt in total:
            id_ = leader_board[amt]
            member = commands.get_user(id_)
            name = member.name
            em.add_field(name=f"{index}. {name}", value=f"{amt}", inline=False)
            if index == x:
                break
            else:
                index += 1
        await ctx.send(embed=em)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`commands` doesn't deal with members.

Use context or the bot user to get the user.

For example

```py
member = ctx.guild.get_member(id_)
```

or

```py
member = self.bot.get_user(id_)
```

Comment: Consider marking the correct solution as correct, you get rep for it too @Wardason

Comment: @Wardason It would be on the side of an answer like a tick just below the downvote one on the left side