# Economy Bot | discord.py rewrite | Leaderboard error - AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I am working on a discord.py economy bot I just get this error.

I try this -----> [Discord.py get_user(id)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66625771/discord-py-get-userid)
But It doesn't work

```
Ignoring exception in command leaderboard:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jerry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "test.py", line 303, in leaderboard
    name = member.name
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jerry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 902, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Jerry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 864, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Jerry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'
```

Is there any way to fix this?

Code:

```py
@client.command(aliases = ["lb"])
async def leaderboard(ctx,x: int = 10):
    users = await get_bank_data()
    leader_board = {}
    total = []
    for user in users:
        name = int(user)
        total_amount = users[user]["wallet"] + users[user]["bank"]
        leader_board[total_amount] = name
        total.append(total_amount)

    total = sorted(total, reverse=True)

    em = discord.Embed(title=f"Top {x} Richest People", color=random.randint(0, 0xffffff))
    index = 1
    for amt in total:
        id_ = leader_board[amt]
        member = ctx.guild.get_member(id_)
        name = member.name
        em.add_field(name=f"{index}. {name}", value=f"{amt}", inline=False)
        if index == x:
            break
        else:
            index += 1
    await ctx.send(embed=em)
```

Comment: What is the `get_member` function?

Comment: bruh read this ------>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66625771/discord-py-get-userid

Comment: bruh - I did. the get_member function isn't there either. I see it probably isn't your code, but you didn't indicate what package you are using so it is hard to tell. Really you should be writing your own minimally reproducible example, and should be pointing people to other questions.

Comment: well, now you changed the link...

Comment: Quite the attitude for someone asking for help... This may point you in the right direction, but can't know for sure since we don't have the entire code. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64221377/discord-py-rewrite-get-member-function-returning-none-for-all-users-except-bot

Comment: downvoting for providing an incorrect link, showing attitude to someone who's trying to help, and then changing it without addressing the change or apologizing

Comment: @AdityaTomar Im sorry i put the wrong one 2 question opened

Comment: @mr_mooo_cow Thanks alot fetch_member works!!!

Comment: @user1558604 Im sorry for changing the link without warnings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for all mistakes but thanks a lot!

thanks to @mr_mooo_cow and @user1558604

The code is

```py
@client.command(aliases = ["lb"])
async def leaderboard(ctx,x: int = 10):
    users = await get_bank_data()
    leader_board = {}
    total = []
    for user in users:
        name = int(user)
        total_amount = users[user]["wallet"] + users[user]["bank"]
        leader_board[total_amount] = name
        total.append(total_amount)

    total = sorted(total, reverse=True)

    em = discord.Embed(title=f"Top {x} Richest People", color=random.randint(0, 0xffffff))
    index = 1
    for amt in total:
        id_ = leader_board[amt]
        member = await ctx.guild.fetch_member(id_) #your existing line
        if member is None:
            raise ValueError(f"Member with id {id_} not found")
        name = member.name
        em.add_field(name=f"{index}. {name}", value=f"{amt}", inline=False)
        if index == x:
            break
        else:
            index += 1
    await ctx.send(embed=em)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.get_member) for `get_member`, if the member is not found it returns None. Thus, since the error you are getting is that 'NoneType' has no attribute 'name,' that suggests that `get_member` returned None and based on the docs it only returns None if the member is not found.

I'd recommend adding

```py
member = ctx.guild.get_member(id_) #your existing line
if member is None:
    raise ValueError(f"Member with id {id_} not found")
```

Adding this if statement will automatically raise an error so that you can see when `get_member` returns None (ie doesn't find the result) so you can handle that appropriately.

Comment: it gives me this  Command raised an exception: ValueError: Member with id 789535039406473276 not found

Comment: Is that expected or not? For some reason `get_member` is not finding a member with the ID you are providing.